# Can you alter a Micronaut App features from the command line?

Tags: micronaut

I created a new Micronaut from the CLI and tinkered around a bit then realized that I could add features from the cli but it seems to only be an option when calling *create-app*.

Is there a way to add features from the command line after the app has been created?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately no, the CLI is limited to project-generation commands (`create-app`, `create-federation`) and code-generation (commands like `create-controller` and `create-client`). It does not have the ability to modify existing projects at this time.

Comment: Is there any plan to add features to existing Micronaut project?

Answer (score 5):

Micronaut CLI has a new command: `feature-diff` that produces the diff of an original project with an original project with additional features specified as a parameter.

Example of a command with reactor feature:

```bash
mn feature-diff --features=reactor
```

Which generates something like this:
[image: Micronaut CLI feature-diff results]

You can store the differences in a file and apply it to your project:

```bash
mn feature-diff --features=reactor > reactor-features.diff
patch -i reactor-features.diff
```

**Note** Micronout CLI provides `-f`, `--force` option to override existing files, however, that option didn't work for me, hence patch option as a workaround.